# Querying multiple WordPress custom fields with AND qualifier

Tags: customization

```
Array
(
    [post_parent] => 101
    [post_type] => page
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [orderby] => title
    [order] => asc
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => rank
                    [value] => Assistant Professor
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => profession
                    [value] => Radiation Oncology
                )

        )

)
```

This looks right to me.  But it's not working! ... Answer?? WP3.1 RC3

Comment: Could you post a dump of the final SQL generated by WP_Query? Easiest way would be by installing the [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin. Or just `var_dump($wp_query->request)`

Comment: Those query params look okay.  Are you absolutely certain that you have a page that matches those criteria *exactly*?

Comment: how's this going? Found an answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the exact way you're doing it. I'm more familiar with the format that Scribu [outlines on his blog](http://scribu.net/wordpress/advanced-metadata-queries.html).

I'd say you should at least be using quote marks on 'rank' and 'Assistant Professor', but there could be more to it.

If that's not working out, you could go old school and use a pre 3.1 solution, such as the one I outlined on the [WordPress.org Support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-fields-search#post-909384). That's using an SQL statement with aliases to find posts based on 4 Custom Fields.

It was posted a couple of years ago, so you might want to revise that for security - it should probably be using the prepare command for a start - but the basic concept should still work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he copied a `var_dump()` of the query vars, since commas and all quote marks are missing. Also, the method you used in that answer is what WordPress does now. I think the questions above need to be answered before any sort of attempt is made at answering the question.